# Tailwind with rollup does not process class attributes

Tags: tailwind-css, rollupjs, postcss, vuejs3

I'm having a bit of a problem to get tailwind working together with rollup to produce a component library with Vue 3. Building and using a component of that output is working fine, however all styles I apply through the class attribute like `class="w-4"` are not being processed and in the consuming application those classes cannot be interpreted. The consuming app is basically just a bare minimum app created with the Vue cli. Components' styles defined in the `<styles>` section with `@apply` work just fine in the consuming app.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- use tailwind classes directly on the class attributes in components of the library
- consume those components in an app that does not have tailwind installed

**What is happening right now:**

- components in the consuming app have the classes as defined (`class="w-4"`) but the app has no rules for them
- components are not styled as they are in the library

**What I tried so far:**

- I tried a plugin `rollup-plugin-tailwind` with no luck.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is just dumb as I just started with rollup.
I'm not sharing my configuration right now in order to get some high level understanding first, but of course I could do that on request.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have not been able to look into it in the last months though.

Comment: I found one issue in my app: The app needs to know the tailwind.config.js so you need to add your tailwind.config.js to your build as well. When you did, you add this config in your apps config with tailwind preset. Hope this helps!